# CloudKit: Using notifications to keep changes in sync across multiple devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, cloudkit

I am writing an app and using CloudKit. The app stores its data in the public database. I’ve created a local cache so that my app can function even if the network isn’t available. I’m using `CKSubscriptions` and the resulting push notifications to keep changes from the cloud in sync. All of this is working well.

Now, if a user has multiple devices and is running my app on all those devices, then I can no longer mark notifications as “read” (using `CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation`) since I won’t know when all the devices have processed them. This is particularly true if one of the devices is offline when a change happens. If I do mark them as read, then when the other devices check for new notifications (using `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation`) they will not see them and their local cache will be out of date.

My current solution is to just leave all notifications in an “unread” state and rely on the `CKServerChangeToken` in `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation` so that each device only grabs the notifications that have occurred since that device last checked. This works well.

But, it seems to me that since I’m not marking any notifications as “read” they will simply continue to pile up on the server. Maybe this isn’t a big deal, but they will take up space and I have no good way to get rid of them. Over time, this seems as if it could be a problem.

Has anyone used subscriptions/notifications in a similar way and come up with a different approach? Also, any feedback on my approach would be welcomed.

Comment: Notifications are for each device. Each device should mark the notifications it gets as read. This shouldn't affect the notifications for the other devices.

Comment: @rmaddy I thought the same thing, but that is not what I'm experiencing. I just did a test with 3 devices. 1st device on WiFi and the other 2 in airplane mode-all signed in to same iCloud account. I made 3 changes using iCloud Dashboard. The 1st device got the notifications properly and updated its data. It marked the notifications as read. I turned off airplane mode on the 2nd device. It got notified that the prior notifications had been read: `notificationType` of `ReadNotification`, but did not receive the change notifications. 3rd device was the same. Doesn't seem correct. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server will delete the old notifications, regardless of the read status.

Comment: Thanks, @Joel. I assumed the same thing when I saw that there is a `CKError` of `CKErrorChangeTokenExpired` which led me to believe that the notifications must get deleted after a time. I appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: But the docs say to pass nil to get all previous notifications if token is expired which would mean the token is deleted from server but not the notifications.

Comment: The Public Database works different. Also, you can't depend on the notifications to sync your data, the notification is only to let you know that something happen.